# Replicating on-prem MS SQL databases with Azure DataFactory

Tags: replication, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to replicate a database from an on-prem SQL server to a SQL Server running on an Azure VM (SQL on IaaS, **not** a SQL Managed Instance or an AzureSQL database) using Azure DataFactory?

Most of the documentation refers to cloud migration, i.e. from on-prem to AzureSQL.

I'm hoping to use Azure DataFactory, rather than log shipping or distributed AGs, or something more near-realtime than hourly backup/FTP/restore.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Log Shipping, or AG? If you're looking for "simple", nothing beats log shipping in this scenario. You wouldn't need FTP for that, either. Just write your log backups somewhere that both servers have access to. I would think you're run into far more complexities trying to use ADF for this.

Comment: In addition to what Brendan said, if your database doesn't have a lot of objects or you only want to replicate a subset of them, I'm personally a fan of [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) itself, a technology meant to be near realtime also. Any reason you wouldn't want to use that? ADF probably can accomplish what you want (since it's just new-age SSIS), but will definitely be more complex and harder to accomplish near realtime synchronization (because of other overhead).

Comment: Would like to keep the management of the solution in Azure, so our (small) team has visibility over it, rather than having to RDP to machines and using SSMS. Also, we don't have redundant SQL skills in our environment, so I'd ideally like a non-SQL specific (as far as it can be) solution. But I take your point on log shipping being the simplest.